# Is the hFE of a bipolar transistor independent of Vce?

Tags: transistors, bjt

In the datasheet they express the hFE for a fixed Vce, sometimes they put 1 V, other times 10 V. But if the gain is independent of Vce this data is not really important, the hFE indicated in the datasheet is valid for any Vce?

Comment: Look up the "Early Effect." Also, don't design for a specific \$h_\text{FE}\$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It varies with, Vce, Ic, temperature...

[image]

And even between two components from the same production line:

[image]

Image credits: 2N4401 [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N4401-D.PDF)

Comment: The variation between 1 and 10 volts seems small .., thanks

Comment: @Mario Sure, you could call that "pretty small" but that's for a "typical" transistor meaning, if you buy 1000 of this model transistor and measure them all, this is the average you get. Now look in the datasheet between what values \$h_{FE}\$ can vary. Note how the "Small signal current gain" varies between 40 and 500! Is that also a small variation? My point: in a circuit design don't rely on \$h_{FE}\$ having a predictable value. \$h_{FE}\$ is **VERY** unpredictable. Luckily in most circuits this is not an issue if you design for the lowest possible value of \$h_{FE}\$.

Comment: I can't find a 2N4401 datasheet with such graphics. I have tried NXP, Fairchild and Vishay. What is the manufacturer of the shown datasheet ? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N4401-D.PDF   Sorry, forgot to put it in the answer